# Should we be concerned about concurrent uploads/downloads and introduce queues, in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-io

If we use ASP.NET Core to receive a lot of requests, most of which involve either downloading a file from the user, or sending a file to another system - should we be concerned about limiting the concurrency of these operations?

The files are relatively large, as such everything is properly being read/sent as a Stream. Memory is highly treasured.

Disk I/O I believe is easily scalable, but I'm not sure if bandwidth is the same case.

Should you realistically allow say up to 100 concurrent connections (download/upload)? If not, are there any controls you can utilize in ASP.NET Core to control this, or will you have to make your own middleware to tackle it?

Comment: What would you like to happen in case the maximum concurrency limit has been reached? Put the request in a queue and force the client to wait for its turn, or deny the download/upload at the moment?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yeah, asynchronously wait for resources to free up. ASP.NET Core supports cancellation for the underlying HTTP request, so if it's a user interaction - we can use that to stop waiting if the user gets annoyed by it and closes the connection before their uploaded file's begun processing.

Comment: Yea, it might be upsetting for the user to see that the download/upload is ongoing (not rejected), but the progress remains on 0% for a long time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias True, but it also depends on who your userbase is and/or use-cases. The important thing to first establish is if such queues are necessary or not. Are these concerns valid? If so, that's all that matters. Solutions can be built following that.